# Draw geom_smooth only for fits that are significant

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

How can I make ggplot plot geom_smooth(method="lm"), but only if it fits some criteria? For instance, if I only want to draw lines if the slope is statistically significant (i.e. *p* from the `lm` fit is less than 0.01).

EDIT: Updated to a more complex example involving facets. Instead of generating the data from scratch, I modified the `diamonds` data set.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

data(diamonds)

set.seed(777)
d <- data.table(diamonds)
d[color %in% c("D","E"), c("x","y") := list(x + runif(1000, -5, 5),
                                            y + runif(1000, -5, 5))] 
plt <- ggplot(d) + aes(x=x, y=y, color=color) + 
    geom_point() + facet_grid(clarity ~ cut, scales="free")
plt + geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

[image]

What I would like is a way to plot all lines except those which do not have statistically significant slopes (i.e. D and E).

Comment: Probably easier to generate the slopes and CI's outside of ggplot

Comment: Or at least fit the models and determine significance outside of ggplot. Then you can pass a subset of the data to `geom_smooth`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can calculate the p-values by group and then subset in `geom_smooth` (per the commenters):

```
# Determine p-values of regression
p.vals = sapply(unique(d$z), function(i) {
  coef(summary(lm(y ~ x, data=d[z==i, ])))[2,4]
})

plt <- ggplot(d) + aes(x=x, y=y, color=z) + geom_point() 

# Select only values of z for which regression p-value is < 0.05   
plt + geom_smooth(data=d[d$z %in% names(p.vals)[p.vals < 0.05],], 
                         aes(x, y, colour=z), method='lm')
```

**UPDATE:** Per your comment, try this, for example:

```
p1 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() + facet_grid(am ~ carb)

dat = data.frame(x=1:5, y=26:30, carb=1:5)

p1 + geom_point(data=dat, aes(x,y), colour="red", size=5)
```

Note that since `dat` has no `am` column, `ggplot` just plots the same values in `dat` for each value of `am`. Of course you can add values for `am` and control what's plotted facet by facet.

**UPDATE 2:** I think this will take care of the faceting case. Note, however, that most of the regressions have p-values less than 0.05, probably because when you have lots of data, even tiny coefficients will be statistically significant.

```
## Create a list holing the p-values for regressions on each 
## combination of color, cut, and clarity
pvals = lapply(levels(d$color), function(i) {
  lapply(levels(d$cut), function(j) {
    lapply(levels(d$clarity), function(k) {
      if(nrow(d[color==i & cut==j & clarity==k, ]) > 1) {
        data.frame(color=i, cut=j, clarity=k, 
                   p.val=coef(summary(lm(y ~ x, data = d[color==i & cut==j & clarity==k, ])))[2,4])
      }
    })
  })
})

# Flatten pvals to a single list level
pvals = unlist(unlist(pvals, recursive=FALSE), recursive=FALSE)

# Turn pvals into a data frame
pvals = do.call(rbind, pvals)

# Keep only rows with p.val < 0.05
pvals = pvals[pvals$p.val < 0.05, ]

plt <- ggplot(d) + aes(x=x, y=y, color=color) + 
  geom_point() + facet_grid(clarity ~ cut, scales="free")

# Create a subset of data frame d containing only combinations of 
# color, cut, and clarity for which we want to plot regression lines
# (you could subset right in the call to geom_smooth, but I thought this would be more clear)
d.subset = d[color %in% pvals$color & 
               cut %in% pvals$cut & 
               clarity %in% pvals$clarity, ]

# Plot regression lines only for groups in d.subset
plt + geom_smooth(data=d.subset, method="lm")
```

Comment: Fair enough, but what if I have facets involves?  In fact, what prompted this question was the fact that what's happening in this plot is actually happening inside each facet of a facet grid.

Comment: Then you could create a data frame with columns `z` and `p.vals` plus another column with the facet variable and feed that to `geom_smooth` with the appropriate subsetting. Then `ggplot` will know which regression lines to draw in each facet. If you post a reproducible example in your question, I'll take a crack at it.

Comment: So ggplot can match aesthetics across different data structures, assuming the names are the same? If so, that's really good to know!

Comment: I've modified my original question to a more complicated example with facets. I'm very curious to see what you come up with. Thanks in advance!